# Generate EC keypair for iOS in NativeScript plugin

Tags: ios, objective-c, signing, key-pair, nativescript-plugin

**Preamble**: I am trying to create an elliptic curve key pair in my NativeScript plugin (*thus I am forced to use Objective-C*) for signing and verification purpose.

At first I want to say that the presented state below is the result of a lot of tries doing it in different ways (I am sitting on this for days, unfortunately) and I considered not only this approach. At the beginning of this project I simply followed the Apple docs and thought I will succeed easily. What a misbelief.

**My requirements**: to keep it easy I want to store the private key inside of the Keychain (Secure Enclave would be the next step), and calculate the public key via `SecKeyCopyPublicKey` after I retrieved the key via `SecItemCopyMatching`, like described in the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/generating_new_cryptographic_keys?language=objc).

**Status quo**: the model for this originally came from the [here](https://github.com/ozgurshn/EncryptionForiOS/blob/master/RsaEncryption/CryptoUtil.m). I never got it working with `SecKeyCreateRandomKey` thus I am trying to use `SecKeyGeneratePair` atm. What I currently implemented looks like this:

```
const privAttr: NSMutableDictionary<string, any> = NSMutableDictionary.new<string, any>();
privAttr.setObjectForKey("my.tag.sign.private", kSecAttrApplicationTag);
privAttr.setObjectForKey(kCFBooleanTrue, kSecAttrIsPermanent);

const pubAttr: NSMutableDictionary<string, any> = NSMutableDictionary.new<string, any>();
pubAttr.setObjectForKey("my.tag.sign.public", kSecAttrApplicationTag);
pubAttr.setObjectForKey(kCFBooleanTrue, kSecAttrIsPermanent);

const param: NSMutableDictionary<string, any> = NSMutableDictionary.new<string, any>();
param.setObjectForKey(kSecAttrKeyTypeECSECPrimeRandom, kSecAttrKeyType);
param.setObjectForKey(256, kSecAttrKeySizeInBits);
param.setObjectForKey(privAttr, kSecPrivateKeyAttrs);
param.setObjectForKey(pubAttr, kSecPublicKeyAttrs);

let pubKeyRef = new interop.Reference<any>();
let privKeyRef = new interop.Reference<any>();
const status = SecKeyGeneratePair(param, pubKeyRef, privKeyRef);
```

Currently I am getting an error -50. According to [OSStatus.com](https://www.osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=-34018) this means that my given parameters are not valid at some point. I do not know what exactly is the problem.

**My question**: how can I generate a keypair where at least the private key is implicitely stored in the keychain and I successfully can retrieve the public key via `SecKeyCopyPublicKey` afterwards.

Thanks for any valuable hint and your help.

Cordially, David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying out several settings I found a solution for this. My answer is documented in the following [GitHub issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/5133).

Best regards,
David